# I get button at the top on asp.net mvc4 Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a following code in View.
I suppose the button should come at the end of field set, but it is coming at the top as shown in the figure.

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>tblCategory</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</fieldset>
```

[image: Layout of webpage]

Comment: Show css for this form, my be some "float" works here.

Comment: it's a big file should I attach it here?

Comment: CSS for editor-label and editor-field.

Answer (score 0):

put it in a `<p>`:

```
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
```